# Cannot get input from input field in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I click the button it should take the input and display the value of the expected delay. The problem is that when I try to take input it does not display anything. I checked it and could not see why it does not work. Here is the code of the webpage:

```js
function predict(){
  var var1 = document.getElementById("var1").value;
  var var2 = document.getElementById("var2").value;
  var var3 = document.getElementById("var3").value;
  var var4 = document.getElementById("var4").value;

  var coef1 = 1, coef2 = 2, coef3 = 3, coef4 = 4;

  var delay = coef1*var1 + coef2*var2 + coef3*var3 + coef4*var4;

  document.getElementById("delay").innerHTML = "<h1>Delay is about " + delay + "  mins</h1>";
}
```

```html
<div id="delay"></div>

<div class="input-box">
  <input type="number" value="1" id="var1">
  <input type="number" value="2" id="var2">
  <input type="number" value="3" id="var3">
  <input type="number" value="4" id="var4">
  <button onclick="predict()">Predict Delay</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fixed your syntax error and now it seems to be working fine. Check it out.

Comment: `<script>`s should always go **right before** the closing `</body>`  tag. Not after.

Comment: Don't use inline `on*` attributes same as you (hopefully) don't use inline `style` attributes. JS, CSS should be in one place only, and that's their respective files or tags.

Comment: `coef*var3` should be `coef3*var3`

Comment: @Yadab You shouldn't be fixing syntax errors  in the question when that is the root of the problem. Let the error be thrown instead, leave a comment about the error and close as a typo. Fixing it in the question simply masks the issue

Comment: Got that. Thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

Your typo error when use `coef3` variable (typed `coef` only)

Change to this line it worked

```
var delay = coef1*var1 + coef2*var2 + coef3*var3 + coef4*var4;
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="delay">
        
    </div>

    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" value="1" id="var1">
        <input type="number" value="2" id="var2">
        <input type="number" value="3" id="var3">
        <input type="number" value="4" id="var4">
        <button onclick="predict()">Predict Delay</button>
    </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function predict(){
        var var1 = document.getElementById("var1").value;
        var var2 = document.getElementById("var2").value;
        var var3 = document.getElementById("var3").value;
        var var4 = document.getElementById("var4").value;

        var coef1 = 1, coef2 = 2, coef3 = 3, coef4 = 4;

        var delay = coef1*var1 + coef2*var2 + coef3*var3 + coef4*var4;
        
        document.getElementById("delay").innerHTML = "<h1>Delay is about " + delay + "  mins</h1>";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reduce values while iterating to a single number result:

```js
const ELs_coef  = document.querySelectorAll(".coef");
const EL_result = document.querySelector("#result");
const coefs = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // Coefficient multipliers per input index

const predictDelay = () => {
  const delay = [...ELs_coef].reduce((a, EL, i) => a + EL.value * coefs[i], 0);
  EL_result.textContent = `Delay is about ${delay} min`;
}

ELs_coef.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("input", predictDelay));
predictDelay();
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <input type="number" value="1" class="coef">
  <input type="number" value="2" class="coef">
  <input type="number" value="3" class="coef">
  <input type="number" value="4" class="coef">
</div>

<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

where `a, EL, i` are the reduce's **accumulator**, the iterating Input **element**, and the current Element **index**.

Alternatively, what you could additionally is:

- store your multipliers directly into every input element **`data-*` attribute**:

```js
const ELs_coef = document.querySelectorAll(".coef");
const EL_result = document.querySelector("#result");

const predictDelay = () => {
  const delay = [...ELs_coef].reduce((a, EL) => {
    a += EL.value * EL.dataset.multiplier
    return a;
  }, 0);
  EL_result.textContent = `Delay is about ${delay} min`;
};

ELs_coef.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("input", predictDelay));
predictDelay();
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <input type="number" value="1" class="coef" data-multiplier="1">
  <input type="number" value="2" class="coef" data-multiplier="2">
  <input type="number" value="3" class="coef" data-multiplier="3">
  <input type="number" value="4" class="coef" data-multiplier="4">
</div>

<h1 id="result"></h1>
```